# ¿Cómo imprimir en la web el número de filas que tiene una columna de una DATABASE?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

En mi **DB** tengo una columna llamada **votos** y quiero saber el total de éstos. Estoy usando el método **COUNT** de **SQL**; y cuando lo aplico en la consola de la misma base de datos, funciona perfecto; pero cuando lo hago desde mi editor de código, con el PHP, no funciona.

```
    $MDB = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'MIBASEDEDATOS' );
$Query = $MDB->query( "SELECT COUNT(voto) FROM MITABLA" );
$ARRAY = $Query->fetch_assoc();
echo $ARRAY['voto'];
```

Cabe destacar que el código de arriba funciona perfectamente cuando en la consulta sql elimino el "COUNT". Por ejemplo, esto funciona: "SELECT voto FROM MITABLA"... Parece que el problemático fuera el "count" pero creo en realidad el problema está en el "fetch".. en la forma de retornar.

Comment: El problema está en que supones que el resultado del `count` llega en una columna llamada `voto` y eso no se especifica en la consulta por ninguna parte. Prueba haciendo `print_r($ARRAY)`

Comment: Tu consulta debería ser algo como `SELECT COUNT(voto)  AS CuentaVotos FROM MITABLA"`, y en el array el índice será `CuentaVotos`

Comment: No entiendo nada. Funciona perfecto cuando no uso el COUNT. Como siempre PHP complicando las cosas con sus excepciones. Se parece al lenguaje castellano.

Comment: @Jakala Me explicas por favor, detalladamente, por qué funciona cuando le pones un alias y por qué debo de hacer eso?

Comment: @user137527 creo que sucede esto: cuando usas una función de agregado, la columna "desaparece", por llamarlo de alguna forma, y se crea otra, que de forma predeterminada no tiene nombre, pues no es lo mismo "voto" que "count(voto)". Cuando le pones un alias a la función de agregado "AS CuentaVotos" ya tienes cómo hacer referencia a esa "nueva" columna, se llama CuentaVotos. Espero haberlo explicado bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) obtiene los datos en forma de arreglo asociativo, donde la clave de cada valor es el nombre de la columna del `SELECT`.

En tu consulta, dado que no has indicado un *alias*, el nombre de la columna vendría a ser `COUNT(voto)` tal cual. Si pruebas esa consulta en la  base de datos directamente verás que ese es el nombre que adquiere la columna.

Para solucionarlo sólo tienes que dar un alias a la columna que resultará del conteo, por ejemplo:

```
$MDB = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'MIBASEDEDATOS' );
$Query = $MDB->query( "SELECT COUNT(voto) total FROM MITABLA" );
$ARRAY = $Query->fetch_assoc();
echo $ARRAY['total'];
```

Aquí hemos dado el alias `total` a la columna, y podremos encontrar el valor por ese índice sin problemas. La palabra reservada `AS` es opcional en las consultas SQL, por eso no lo he puesto, esta consulta: `SELECT COUNT(voto) total FROM MITABLA` y esta `SELECT COUNT(voto) AS total FROM MITABLA` son equivalentes.

Si no quieres usar *alias*, entonces puedes usar el método [`fetch_row()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) en lugar de `fetch_assoc()`.

Como indica el Manual de PHP, este método:

> Obtiene una fila de datos del conjunto de resultados y la devuelve
>   como un array enumerado, donde cada columna es almacenada en un índice
>   del array comenzando por 0 (cero). Cada llamada subsiguiente a esta
>   función devolverá la siguiente fila del conjunto de resultados, o NULL
>   si no hay más filas.

Veamos:

```
$MDB = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'MIBASEDEDATOS' );
$Query = $MDB->query( "SELECT COUNT(voto) total FROM MITABLA" );
$ARRAY = $Query->fetch_row();
echo $ARRAY[0];
```

Dado que `fetch_row()` devuelve los datos en forma de arreglo enumerado, el valor se encontrará en el índice `0` del arreglo, que sería la primera columna (y única columna)  que devolvería esta consulta.

Si ejecutaras una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT id, voto, nombre FROM TUTABLA;
```

y usaras `fetch_row` para obtener los datos:

```
$row=$query->fetch_row();
```

El valor de `id` se encontraría en `$row[0]`, el valor de `voto` se encontraría en `$row[1]` y el valor de `nombre` se encontraría en `$row[2]`. Eso no tiene nada que ver con el orden que tienen las columnas en la tabla, sino con el orden que tienen en el `SELECT`. Imaginemos una consulta así:

```
SELECT nombre, voto, id FROM TUTABLA;

          ^      ^    ^
          0      1    2
```

El valor de `id` estaría en `$row[2]`, el valor de `voto` estaría en `$row[1]` y el valor de `nombre` estaría en `$row[0]`, **independientemente de que `id` sea la primera columna de la tabla**, porque en este `SELECT` el valor de `id` viene en la posición `2`, no en la posición `0`.

Comment: creo que a tu primer codigo le falta la palabra reservada AS. Y en tu segundo codigo sobra la palabra TOTAL. Lo que no entiendo es por que en el segundo codigo, donde usas el FETCH_ROW, usas el indice "0". Si en mi tabla tengo 3 columnas: la primera es ID, la segunda VOTO y la tercera MAIL. ¿Acaso no deberia ser asi la orden "ARRAY[1]"??.... y sin embargo cuando hago esto da error. Se supone que el valor 0 llamaria a la columna ID

Comment: @user137527 la palabra reservada `AS` es opcional, si pruebas la consulta sin ella funciona de igual modo. En cuanto a lo segundo, los índices de los arrays empiezan por `0`. Además, `fetch_row` (y todos los demás métodos `fetch`), **trabajan con las columnas del `SELECT`** no con las columnas de la tabla. O sea, si sólo pones una columna en el `SELECT` el índice `0`  es de esa columna. O si pones un `SELECT laUltima, laCuarta ...` el índice `0` será de `laUltima` y el índice `1` será de `laCuarta` porque así escribiste el `SELECT`. Y, aunque ponga el *alias* no afecta el funcionamiento.

Comment: Pero si por ejemplo, yo tengo tres columnas en mi tabla: id, name, mail. Y hago la siguiente consulta: $QUERY= query("SELECT * FROM miTabla"). Y luego retorno los datos asi: $QUERY->FETCH_ROW(); echo $QUERY[0]. Aqui lo que recibiria seria la columna ID. Pero en cambio con el COUNT es diferente, cuando yo llamo al indice 0 , siguiendo la logica de arriba, deberia retornarme la columna id, o al menos un error, esperando que llame $ARRAY[1]....eso no entiendo, por que es diferente ?

Comment: @user137527 Es que `fetch_row()` trabaja con los resultados del `SELECT`, no tiene nada que ver por cómo estén las columnas de la tabla. Si tú haces algo así por ejemplo: `SELECT id as cero, id as uno, id as dos FROM tuTabla`, observa que obtendrás tres veces el resultado de la columna  `id` ¿no?, pues el índice `0` será el valor de la columna cuyo alias es `cero`, el índice `1` el de la columna cuyo alias es `uno` y el índice `2` de la columna cuyo alias es `dos`. Y si  usas `fetch_assoc` tendrías que buscar el dato mediante `$ARRAY['cero'], $ARRAY['uno'], $ARRAY['dos']`

Comment: Creo que ya te comprendí a mi manera..pero no estoy seguro. Corrígeme si me equivoco por favor: Si yo hago la siguiente consulta "SELECT * FROM table", al momento de llamar a la columna VOTO (recuerda que tengo 3 columnas: id, voto y mail ) tendria que hacerlo de esta manera: "$ARRAY = QUERY->FETCH_ROW(); echo $ARRAY[1]". Esto Debido a q estoy llamando a TODAS las columnas.. Sin embargo, cuando uso el "SELECT COUNT(voto) FROM tabla"... estoy seleccionando solo la columna VOTO, por lo tanto, la llamada al array ya no sería asi "ARRAY[1]" sino asi "ARRAY[0]" porque solo estoy tomando UNA columna

Comment: @user137527 no es del todo así. 1º. Cuando haces un `SELECT * FROM ...`, si ejecutas `$ARRAY[1]` vas a obtener el valor de la columna `voto`, porque como dije antes, los índices empiezan por `0`, ¿se entiende ese punto? 2º. Cuando haces un `SELECT COUNT(voto) FROM tabla` no estás seleccionando la columna `voto` en realidad, sino que haces un conteo de todas las filas basado en la columna `voto`. Esa consulta arroja una sola columna (que es el resultado del conteo) y para alcanzarla tendrías que hacer `$ARRAY[0]` por cuanto es la primera (y única) columna que arroja esa consulta. ¿Se entiende?

Comment: se entiende...mas o menos es lo que yo decia. Si puedes edita tu respuesta para darte los puntos. Porque la primera respuesta no esta clara . Esto ultimo que me has explicado, agregalo.

Comment: @user137527 acabo de editar, me parece que así queda bastante claro.